# Tengo unas dudas en lo que respecta a los action de html y las url en ajax de Jquery

Tags: php, html, jquery

Estoy implementando algunas cosas a un sistema de facturación electrónica que esta hecho con PHP y Jquery en MVC - POO y me he percatado de que en los "action" de html y en las "url" de las peticiones ajax se referencian las rutas o url a donde se hacen las peticiones de la siguiente manera:

- En el caso de html en los action ponen la ruta de esta manera  `<form action="<?=$url?>/ventas/ctrReporteCreditos" method="post">...` siendo **$url** el dominio de la página, **ventas** el archivo **.php**  y ctrReporteCreditos es el metodo a donde se dirigen las variables post del formulario.
- En el caso de ajax ocurre lo mismo en las url donde se ingresa la ruta a donde se realizara la petición lo hacen de la siguiente manera `$.ajax({type:"POST",url:baseurl+'compras/rucapirest',...` de la misma manera siendo **baseurl** el dominio de la pagina, **compras** es el archivo **.php** y **rucapirest** es el método a donde se envían las variables post , mi duda se centra en como hacen en el sistema para poder enviar directamente las variables post a un metodo en particular ya que por lo que yo tengo entendido en los action de html y en las url de las peticiones ajax se ponen las rutas con sus extensiones como ejemplo:
- `<form action="documento.php" method="post">...`
- `$.ajax({type:"POST",url:'documento.php',...`

Se que en este sistema deben de estar usando alguna configuración mediante javascript o jquery pero no logro encontrar dicho código así que espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Normalmente lo que se hace es que se envía un parámetro en la url ya sea por ajax o en action del form y dependiendo de este parámetro se llama al método que se requiera, es decir pones en el form:

```
<form action="documento.php?opc=1" method="post">
```

y en documento.php pones algo asi:

```
<?php

$opc = $_REQUEST['opc'];

if($opc = 1){
  metodo();
}
else if($opc = 2){
  metodo();
}
else{
 metodo3();
}
```